# Transparency in ProcessingJS in OpenGL mode

Tags: opengl, transparency, processing

When I try to render transparent shapes in Processing using OpenGL mode (`fill(r, g, b, a)`), it works fine. However, when I use the same code in ProcessingJS, transparency is ignored and my shapes are opaque. I have seen [this ticket](http://processing-js.lighthouseapp.com/projects/41284/tickets/1976-alpha-value-in-fill-not-working-in-3d), and it seems no one has done anything about this for a while.

Is there some way to force ProcessingJS to render with transparency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is some sort of quirk or bug in ProcessingJS, but if you enable lights, opacity works fine. If your code doesn't need lights, just use

```
ambientLight(255);
```

This took a while to figure out, so it would be nice if ProcessingJS had some documentation on this...